# Is god shiva immortal?

Tags: shiva

According to one story god shiva became unconscious due to drinking of the poison halahal from samudra manthan and goddess tara had to come to his rescue.In different versions of the story goddess manasa comes to his rescue while in some other versions goddess parvati drinks some of the poison ,loses control and turns into goddess kali. It is also said parvati grabs god shiva's throat , wraps the snake vasuki around his neck to save shiva . Which is true?

Comment: Kali, Tara are Aadi Shakti which are essentially non-different from lord Shiva... so it's just a play...

Comment: It's just leela of Shiva- Shakti.

Comment: Question body and title are different. Is this the question about seeking stories you've mentioned or is it about the immortality of Shiva?

Answer (score 2):

Lord shiva is immortal no question here.
Immortality has been asked to lord shiva in mahamrityunjaya mantra.
and those stories yes, i can not completely disagree as above said tezz then also i would like to give refrence from mahabharata and ramayana.

> But with the churning still going on, the poison Kalakuta appeared at last. Engulfing the Earth it suddenly blazed up like
>   a fire attended with fumes. And by
>   the scent of the fearful Kalakuta, the
>   three worlds were stupefied. And
>   then Siva, being solicited by
>   Brahman, swallowed that poison for
>   the safety of the creation. **The divine
>   Maheswara held it in his throat, and
>   it is said that from that time he is
>   called Nilakantha (blue-throated).**
>   Seeing all these wondrous things,
>   the Asuras were filled with despair,
>   and got themselves prepared for
>   entering into hostilities with the
>   gods for the possession of Lakshmi
>   and Amrita.
>
> — The Mahabharata, Book 1: Adi
>   Parva: Astika Parva: Section
>   XVIII

source— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01019.htm

> अथ वर्ष सहस्रेण योक्त्र सर्प शिरांसि च | वमन्तो अति विषम् तत्र ददंशुर्
>
> "After a thousand years,
>   the Thousand-headed serpent
>   Vaasuki, which is being used as
>   churning rope, is incapacitated
>   to bear the friction of churning
>   and fanged the cliffs of Mt.
>   Mandara. Thereby a great lot
>   of venom is disgorged from the
>   heads of that serpent Vaasuki,
>   which venom on melting the
>   rocks of Mt. Mandara became
>   the holocaustic poison called
>   haalahala .
>
> उत्पपाताम् अग्नि संकाशम्
>   हालाहल महाविषम् |
>   तेन दग्धम् जगत् सर्वम् स देव
>   असुर मानुषम् || १-४५-२०
>
> "A lethal poison similar
>   to inferno known as haalahala
>   has started to fulminate
>   therefrom, by which whole
>   universe of gods, non-gods
>   and humans is burnt down.
>
> अथ देवा महादेवम् शंकरम्
>   शरणार्थ्तिनः |
>   जग्मुः पशुपतिम् रुद्रम् त्राहि
>   त्राहि इति तुष्टुवुः || १-४५-२१
>
> "The gods seeking
>   shelter then approached Rudra,
>   the Cardinal God, Endower of
>   Solace, and who husbands all
>   the created animals inclusive
>   of human-animals, namely
>   Shiva, and they prayed to him
>   saying 'save, save
>   us.' [1-45-21]
>
> एवम् उक्{]तः ततो देवैः देवेश्वरः
>   प्रभुः |
>   प्रादुर् आसीत् ततो अत्र एव
>   शंख चक्र धरो हरिः ||
>   १-४५-२२
>
> "This way while the
>   gods are praying the Lord and
>   God of Gods, namely Shiva,
>   then handling his disc and
>   conch-shell Vishnu has also
>   revealed himself at that place.
>   [1-45-22]
>
> उवाच एनम् स्मितम् कृत्वा रुद्रम्
>   शूलधरम् हरिः |
>   दैवतैः मध्यमानो तु तत् पूर्वम्
>   समुपस्थितम् || १-४५-२३
>   तत् त्वदीयम् सुरश्रेष्ठः सुराणाम्
>   अग्रतो हि यत् |
>   अग्र पूजामि इह स्थित्वा गृहाण
>   इदम् विषम् प्रभो || १-४५-२४
>
> "And Vishnu smilingly
>   spoke to wielder of trident
>   Rudra, 'oh, god the best,
>   whatever element that has
>   emerged from the churning of
>   Milk Ocean by gods, that shall
>   belong to you, isn't it. By
>   virtue of your position as the
>   foremost god among gods, oh,
>   omnicompetent god Shiva, you
>   please accept this poison
>   applying yourself to that
>   position of foremost god, and
>   deeming this poison, haalahala,
>   as a foremost oblation to your
>   godhood. [1-45-23, 24]
>
> इति उक्त्वा च सुरश्रेष्ठः तत्र
>   एव अंतर्धीयत |
>   देवतानाम् भयम् दृष्ट्वा श्रुत्वा
>   वाक्यम् तु शारङ्गिणः ||
>   १-४५-२५
>   हालाहलम् विषम् घोरम् संजग्राह
>   अमृत उपमम् |
>
> "Saying so Vishnu, the
>   best one among gods, has
>   disappeared then and there
>   only. And on observing the
>   scare of gods and also on
>   paying heed to the words of the
>   Wielder of Bow called
>   shaara~Nga , namely Vishnu,
>   **god Shiva gulped that lethal
>   poison, haalahala , as if it is
>   ambrosia.** [1-45-25, 26a]
>
> —Valmiki ramayana:Book I : Bala Kanda - 
>   Sarga 45

source:— http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga45/bala_45_frame.htm

There are a lot of versions of story of samudra manthan which varies from puran to purana so it is not easy to say a single true story in purans but yes in epics(mahabharata,ramayana) he is lord shiva only who drinks the poison.